# Testing firebase functions locally

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I am new to firebase. Trying to figure out how it works. I have successfully created and deployed a firebase function. When I am trying to run it locally then I am getting an error.

So, When I started looking at how to run firebase functions locally. I found this two ways.

1)`firebase serve` command

2) Using firebase emulator https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator

When I am trying to run with the second way it's working well I can make a call to functions locally and I can add data to firestore.

But when I am trying to run functions locally using the `firebase serve` this is the error I am getting.

```
=== Serving from '/Users/shashank/Desktop/Learning Projects/socialApp'...

⚠  Your requested "node" version "8" doesn't match your global version "12"
✔  functions: Emulator started at http://localhost:5000
i  functions: Watching "/Users/shashank/Desktop/Learning Projects/socialApp/functions" for Cloud Functions...
✔  functions[helloWorld]: http function initialized (http://localhost:5000/socialapp-8f2db/us-central1/helloWorld).
✔  functions[getScreams]: http function initialized (http://localhost:5000/socialapp-8f2db/us-central1/getScreams).
✔  functions[createStreams]: http function initialized (http://localhost:5000/socialapp-8f2db/us-central1/createStreams).
i  functions: Beginning execution of "createStreams"
>  Error: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more information.
>      at GoogleAuth.getApplicationDefaultAsync (/Users/shashank/Desktop/Learning Projects/socialApp/functions/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:161:19)
>      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
>      at async GoogleAuth.getClient (/Users/shashank/Desktop/Learning Projects/socialApp/functions/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:503:17)
>      at async GrpcClient._getCredentials (/Users/shashank/Desktop/Learning Projects/socialApp/functions/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/grpc.js:108:24)
>      at async GrpcClient.createStub (/Users/shashank/Desktop/Learning Projects/socialApp/functions/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/grpc.js:229:23)
```

I wanted to learn what's going wrong with this method. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have a credentials problem. You will need to post your code to get answers. Start by setting up the environment variable  `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`. Read this link for more information: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production

Comment: If you have reliable and predictable steps to reproduce this erro *from scratch*, please post this issue to GitHub. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Comment: I did set up the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` but it didn't work @JohnHanley

Comment: Sure will post on Github page @DougStevenson

Comment: The error message indicates that you did not set up the environment credentials correctly: `Could not load the default credentials`. Check the spelling, verify that the variable points to a valid file, etc.

Comment: It's so weird. I regenerated a new key for the App Engine default service account and updated my `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` then it started working. @JohnHanley